# Remmina: cannot connect to remote server using SSH, but I can SSH from shell

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, openssh, vnc, ssh-tunnel

The following seems to be a common problem, but I have not found anything to resolve the problem in my case. I have 2 laptops ARTHUR and GALAHAD. ARTHUR is running ubuntu 16.04 (32 bit), GALAHAD is running ubuntu 18.04. I can SSH from GALAHAD to ARTHUR from a shell with no problems using Public Keys. If I try to connect to ARTHUR from GALAHAD using Remmina (via VNC) it works OK if I use password authentication in the SSH tunnelling, but this is not very secure. If I try to use Public key (automatic), after entering the SSH private key passphrase I get this message:

> *ssh automatic public key authentication failed: failed to read key:
>   /home/stuart/.ssh/authorized_keys*

If instead I try to use 'identity file' and select '~/.ssh/authorized_keys' I get the following message:

> *SSH public key authentication failed: Access denied.*

I think this is not an SSH issue because I can connect using SSH from a shell, I think this is a Remmina issue. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Same issue over here, did you have any luck @StuartM?

Answer (score 0):

Probably an issue with Remmina not receiving the keys (or key-reading permissions) needed to make the connection. It sounds like:

1. You are using the Remmina GUI, and
2. Remmina is forcing you to configure something that the shell `ssh` command handles implicitly.

The second warning looks familiar: ['identity file' sounds like a private key](https://serverfault.com/q/546144). I know they call it "public key" authentication, but that may refer to ARTHUR's point of view: it will decide whether to grant access to GALAHAD based on the public key.

authorized_keys is not a private key file; it is a list of the [public keys of that can sign in as the user](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/authorized_keys/) in whose .ssh folder it is located. The file is relevant on the receiving computer, and probably does not contain the receiving computer's public key. If key-based SSH is working for you, then ARTHUR likely has an authorized_keys containing GALAHAD's public key.

If key-based SSH succeeds without specifying a key, then I expect the private key to be ~/.ssh/id_rsa (public key in id_rsa.pub, should you need it). Try using that pair in Remmina.